# Dev c++ 5.11 on Windows 8 Produces wrong answer

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
class Number
{
    private:

    int x, y;

    public:

    Number()
    {
    x = y = 100;
    }

void avg()
{
    std::cout<<"x = "<<std::cout<<x;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Y =  "<<std::cout<<y;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Average =  "<<std::cout<<(x+y)/2;
}

};

     main() 
    {

    Number n;
    n.avg();

    }
```

This programme runs but shows wrong answer, may be showing addresses of memory locations instead of showing the assigned values of 100. Please correct me why it is behaving like this?

Comment: It does not produce the "wrong answer". _You_ made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::cout << "x = " << std::cout << x;
```

is wrong. You need

```
std::cout << "x = " << x;
```

Otherwise, the `std::cout` stream object in `...<< std::cout` is implicitly converted to a `(void*)` when invoking `operator<<` on it, and therefore the pointer (an address) is displayed.

The conversion to `void*` exists for historic reasons ([the safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)), but in C++11 was removed, due to the introduction of explicit conversion operators, so your code should not compile in C++11.